# Issue Sending Mail through GMail SMTP Using PEAR

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, pear

For the past day or two, I have been receiving this error:

`Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (code: -1, response: )]`

We just set up a new linux server (running CentOS), and I have all the necessary packages installed, PEAR, SMTP, etc.  This is a known working script, and I have never had any issues in the past sending through Gmail.  Now to me it seems to be a DNS issue, because I am able to substitute in the IP address, and it will work - intermittently - meaning some of the mail goes through sometimes.  I've disabled SELinux, and even ran it with our firewall off, so I'm kind of at an impasse.  Any suggestions as to what this may be, or what I might be able to do to resolve the issue?

Edit: Rebooted the server and router, and it seems to be going through correctly.  Although this is good in the short term, it still has me nervous.  Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: Do you have permissions to use the gmail SMTP server in the first place? If you're using gmail as a business service, google may provide you with the solution to this.

Comment: Yes, this is a business service.  My last resort was to call them; however, my assumption is that they're going to tell me everything is OK on their end, and it must be a setting on our server or firewall, so that's why I'm trying to attempt a few solutions myself first.

Comment: The error message indicates a DNS failure.

Comment: That's what I assumed as well; however, even when substituting in the IP address, it would still only perform intermittently before producing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Sending HTML message through PEAR while using SMTP authentication returns an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166468/sending-html-message-through-pear-while-using-smtp-authentication-returns-an-err?rq=1) you need to set the google address as "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com"