# Sending HTML message through PEAR while using SMTP authentication returns an error

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, pear

I'm trying to send an HTML message while using SMTP authentication to Gmail in PHP. Here is the script that I am using:

```
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once 'Mail/mime.php';

$from = "Some Name <myemail@gmail.com>";
$to = "Other Name <otheremail@gmail.com>";
$subject = "This is a test";
$crlf = "\n";

$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$password = "mypass";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
                  'Return-Path' => $from,
                  'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setTXTBody("This is a test email message");
$mime->setHTMLBody($body);
$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
```

**Note:** the `$body` is an HTML table with images and other info.

When I execute the script it fails with the following error:

> Failed to set sender: Some name [SMTP: Invalid response code
>   received from server (code: 555, response: 5.5.2 Syntax error.
>   c6sm20541406obd.22)]

Here is what I've tried to see what is going wrong:
1. Using the same script using 'Mail' instead of 'smtp' i.e.

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('Mail');
```

This works just fine.
2. Using the same script w/o the **mime.php**, this also works but doesn't allow one to send an HTML email.

Does anybody know how I can combine the two so that I'm still using SMTP authentication **and** send an HTML message?

**EDIT:**
Here is the dump of `$mime->headers()`:

```
[MIME-Version] => 1.0
[From] => Some Name
[Return-Path] => Some Name
[Subject] => This is a test
[Content-Type] => multipart/alternative;
boundary="=_8662996a1f586248545d9f01f48e916d"
```

Comment: Can you dump `$mime->headers()` please?

Comment: I added the dump to the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself finally.

Thanks to [Abid Hussain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1547438/abid-hussain) for providing the link to the example here: http://tonyvirelli.com/slider/php-html-email-using-smtp/

**Solution:**

1. Remove the `'Return-Path' => $from` from the headers array.
2. Add `To => $to` to the headers array(without this, the **to** header of the received email is *Undisclosed recipients*)

Answer (score 2):

See the below URL I think it is very help full to you.

[How to send an HTML email using SMTP in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814910/how-to-send-an-html-email-using-smtp-in-php)

The Gmail's SMTP server address is **SMTP.GOOGLEMAIL.COM** not **SMTP.GMAIL.COM**.

Therefore Your settings should be:

```
// ...
$smtp=array();
$smtp['host']='ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
```

**See another example:-**

**Send An HTML & Plain Text Email Using An SMTP Server With PHP & PEAR**

http://tonyvirelli.com/slider/php-html-email-using-smtp/

Comment: googlemail.com is an alias of gmail.com both domains can be used interchangeably. The link you have provided at the end was very useful, so I gave you the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: Google search suggested info box recommends to use gmail.com not googlemail.com: googling "gmail smtp settings" shows in a box at the top "If you connect using SMTP, you can only send mail to Gmail or Google Apps users; if you connect using SSL/TLS, you can send mail to anyone. If your device or application supports SSL - connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 465. To connect with SSL, you need to provide a Google username and password for authentication."

Answer (score 1):

Try embracing the names in double quotes, like so:

```
$from = '"Some Name" <myemail@gmail.com>';
$to = '"Other Name" <otheremail@gmail.com>';
```

try it and tell us about it.

**Update**:
Ok, above didn't work, so I just would tell you what it's working for me in my php pages to send emails through smtp gmail.

- I use http://phpmailer.sourceforge.net/
- smtp server set to **smtp.gmail.com**
- it uses **TLS** protocol in port **587**

so based on that you could try to change your config to:

```
$host = "tls://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "587";
```

you can see [**here**](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail) how to send mail through gmail with phpmailer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this returns another error: Failed to set sender: "Some Name" -- this time it has the double quotes :/

Comment: Thanks for the update, I've already found the solution.(see below)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and via debugging managed to get all kinds of different errors (below).  Strangest thing is that it completely stopped working on about 11/2/2017.  I didn't do any updates.  Previously it would randomly work so I put in a retry and it always succeeded < 5 tries, until the 2nd.  Strange.

```
Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: -1, response: )]
fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto
fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error)
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

(and so on)

Another used posted this troubleshooting step that helped me get more errors so I could Google more what could be the cause:

```
$result = fsockopen('ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 465, $error_no,
$error_message, 5);     
if($result === false) {         
    echo "error no:
$error_no error message: $error_message";       echo print_r($result,true);     
}else{      
    echo 'success\n\n';
}
```

**My fix** was to add a CA bundle file, since apparantly PHP couldn't verify the cert of Google:

- Download CA bundle https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html & extract to C:\Program Files\PHP\ssl\cacert.pem
- Specify location in php.ini: openssl.cafile = C:\Program Files\PHP\ssl\cacert.pem