# i am trying to send email but its giving this error( verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in )

Tags: php

This code is giving the error that its not connected to mail server.Can any one solve it thanks for your help in advance.

```
<?php

ini_set('SMTP','myserver');
ini_set('smtp_port',25);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
 $name=$_POST["name"]."<br>";
 $email=$_POST["email"]."<br>";
 $subject=$_POST["subj"]."<br>";
 $comment=$_POST["comments"];
 $to="younas_510@yahoo.com";
$headers="From: $name<$email>";
 $messege="Name:$name \n\nEmail:$email \n\n Subject:$subject\n\nMessege:$comment";

 if(mail($to,$subject,$messege,$headers)){

    echo"Email sent";
 }else{
        echo "Please try again";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you running it locally?  if yes check these:-  [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591329/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25-verify-your-smtp-and), [Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25),[Third](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981027/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25-verify-your-smtp),[Fourth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836282/php-function-mail-isnt-working)

Comment: yes i am running in xampp

Comment: Why are you reading only half of the comment ? you answered "yes" to his question but did you both going over the links he provided ?